# Get 24 bit PNG pixel value

Tags: java, android, png, bitmapfactory

I'm decoding a **24 bit** single channel grayscale PNG with `BitmapFactory` (`Config.ARGB_8888`).
Now I'v tried several ways (described here) to get the value of a pixel, but none returned the value I'm expecting.

This one should give me the value for a 16 bit PNG, but doesn't seem to work in the 24 bit case:

```
int val = bitmap.getPixel(0,0)&0x0000ffff;
```

What's the right way to adress the value of a 24 bit PNG?

Answer (score 1):

```
int val = bitmap.getPixel(0,0)&0x00ffffff;
```